# Vue.js v-model inside v-html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to store html inside variable. Example:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    my_html: '<input type="text" v-model="data"'
  }
}
```

And I want to receive in data the value that user enters in the field. But this connection does not work
Full example:

```
var test = new Vue({
  el: '#some_id',
  data: function() {
    return {
      data: '',
      my_html: '<input type="text" v-model="data" />'
    }
  },
  template: 
    '<div>
      <input type="text" v-model="data" />
      <input type="text" v-model="data" />
      <span v-html="my_html"></span>
    </div>'
});
```

In this example, the first two inputs will normally link with data and with each other, but the third (the one inside span) won’t

Comment: You'll need a dynamic component instead of `v-html`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53545138/392102)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically replaced text string with Vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542295/dynamically-replaced-text-string-with-vue-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the official doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) :

> The contents of the span will be replaced with the value of the `rawHtml` property, interpreted as plain HTML - data bindings are ignored. Note that you cannot use v-html to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition

for more details try to check @RoyJ's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542295/dynamically-replaced-text-string-with-vue-component/53545138#53545138)