# best practise to render html strings that contain components in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Blog/News kind of Website which means there will be Posts, they have a content which is a string of HTML stored in my database.

Since I also need stuff like Sliders and so on which won´t get generated via `v-html` I thought about what is the best practice to render a HTML String I retrieve from the Database on the Website Frontend.

I readed the Vue Docs about Render Functions but wasn´t able to solve my problem with the information there.

Example HTML String for understanding

```
<div class="slidercontainer">
   <slider :options="optionPreset1"></slider>
</div>
```

I save those presets in the finished Post Component. If there is any better way to solve this kind of thing with a DB then tell me, its not in Production yet so I can change such crucial things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542295/dynamically-replaced-text-string-with-vue-component).